# How to only draw an inside or outside stroke around a polygon in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, sld

If I add a stroke to a polygon SLD style, I get something that extends over both sides of the polygon boundary like this:

[image]

I want to highlight certain polygons, some without drawing anything over their area, others without drawing anything over their neighbors. So the stroke should only be on the inside OR outside instead like in these:

[image]

How can I achieve this in GeoServer SLD in an easy, fast and hopefully non-hacky way? I need to be able to specify the width in "drawing units", not my geometry's coordinate system units so the suggestions from the similar [Line stroke offset in Geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78167/line-stroke-offset-in-geoserver) do not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<PerpendicularOffset>5</PerpendicularOffset>`

A positive value places the offset line on the left of the line. In the example above the offset is 5 pixels.  You can then specify the line thickness, so if you want an inner line 10 pixels wide and touching the perimeter, I would try setting the offset to 5 and the line thickness to 10.  A negative value places the offset on the other side of the line.

See the documentation [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/polygons.html) for 'Offset Inner Lines'.  (I have a feeling this may be a new feature since the previous thread you reference was written).

Comment: Unfortunately that is a GeoServer 2.9 addition, I am stuck on 2.8.2 for the time being. :(

Answer (score 2):

For GeoServer 2.8.x you can use compositing to achieve a "inner stroke" effect, see here: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/composite-blend/example.html